# Java freeze when not debugging or printing

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm

I've created a simple closest point algorithm application with a nice UI for school homework.

Problem is, I'm getting very weird freezes when I stop the algorithm to rerun it. It only happens when I'm not debugging and not writing console output for some reason.

When I click the button to run the algorithm again the first run is supposed to stop calculation. But for some reason it only does that when I either debug or write to console, in the other case it just finishes up its calculation. The freeze itself is pretty obvious because I'm doing a `thread.join()` on the GUI thread, but the fact that the algorithm doesn't break is kinda weird.

This is the algorithm class:

```
public class Bruteforce extends Algorithm
{

    public Bruteforce( AlgorithmListener listener )
    {
        super( listener );
    }

    public void runAlgorithm()
    {
        EditablePair pair = new EditablePair();

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        for ( int i = 0; i < pointlist.size() - 1 && keepRunning; i++ )
        {
            // Uncomment next line or run in debug and freeze doesn't happen
            //System.out.print( (keepRunning ? 1 : 0) );

            Point pi = pointlist.get( i );
            for ( int j = i + 1; j < pointlist.size() && keepRunning; j++ )
            {
                Point pj = pointlist.get( j );

                long d = pi.calculateSquaredDistanceTo( pj );

                if ( d < pair.distance || pair.distance == -1 )
                {
                    pair.distance = d;
                    pair.a = pi;
                    pair.b = pj;
                }
            }
        }

        int calculationtime = (int) ( System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime );
        if(!keepRunning)
            listener.onCalculated( null , -1 , -1 );
        listener.onCalculated( new Pair( pair ) , calculationtime , 0 );
    }
}
```

Algorithm superclass:

```
public abstract class Algorithm implements Runnable
{   
    public boolean visualizeOutput = false;

    protected AlgorithmListener listener;
    protected boolean keepRunning;
    protected Thread thread;

    private ArrayList<Point> tmpList;
    protected ArrayList<Point> pointlist;

    public Algorithm(AlgorithmListener listener)
    {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public void process(ArrayList<Point> pointlist)
    {
        System.out.println("Pre Start 1");
        tmpList = pointlist;
        System.out.println("Pre Start 2");
        listener.onStatusChanged( "Cancelling Previous Run..." );
        stopAndJoin();
        System.out.println("Pre Start 3");
        start();
    }

    public void start()
    {
        keepRunning = true;

        thread = new Thread(this);
        System.out.println("Post Start 1");
        thread.start();
        System.out.println("Post Start 2");
    }

    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("Pre Run 1");
        listener.onStatusChanged( "Copying Point List..." );
        this.pointlist = new ArrayList<>(tmpList);
        System.out.println("Pre Run 2");
        listener.onStatusChanged( "Calculating..." );
        System.out.println("Pre Run 3");
        runAlgorithm();
        System.out.println("Post Run 1");
    }

    public abstract void runAlgorithm();

    public void stop()
    {
        keepRunning = false;
    }

    public void stopAndJoin()
    {
        stop();
        if(thread != null)
            try
            {
                thread.join();
            }
            catch( InterruptedException e )
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

It's only noticable when you run on 50.000+ points and press the button again after the first calculation started

console output goes

```
Pre Start 1
Pre Start 2
Pre Start 3
Post Start 1
Post Start 2
Pre Run 1
Pre Run 2
Pre Run 3
Pre Start 1
Pre Start 2
```

and the UI freezes until calculations are done, and then it runs again

```
([43768, 37240], [43769, 37240]) Distance = 1
Post Run 1
Pre Start 3
Post Start 1
Post Start 2
Pre Run 1
Pre Run 2
Pre Run 3
([43768, 37240], [43769, 37240]) Distance = 1
Post Run 1
```

I have no idea why this is happening and how to prevent it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not tested this myself, but the thing that stands out is that this might because your variable `keepRunning` is stale. If this variable is being access from different threads, you should really make it `volatile` to ensure it is access correctly from different threads.

So change this:

```
protected boolean keepRunning;
```

to this:

```
protected volatile boolean keepRunning;
```

For more information have a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html).